# Apex test class not working

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, failing-tests, after-trigger

I have written a trigger that automatically assigns the value of the 'Status' field from the EmailMessage object to a custom field called 'Last Email Status' on Case object.

Below is my method which works absolutely fine:

Apex method:

```
public static void updateCaseLastEmailStatus(List<EmailMessage> emUpdateCase) {
        
        Id caserecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('CaseRecordPage').getRecordTypeId();
        
        Map<Id,Case> caseUpdate = new Map<Id,Case>();
        List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();
        
        for (EmailMessage eMsg : emUpdateCase) {
            listIds.add(eMsg.RelatedToId);
        }
           
        caseUpdate = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT Last_Email_Status__c,
                                       (SELECT Status 
                                        FROM EmailMessages 
                                        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1 )
                                       From Case WHERE RecordTypeId = :caserecordType AND ID IN:  listIds]);
                          
           for(Id caseId : caseUpdate.keyset()) {
               Case myCase = caseUpdate.get(caseId);
               myCase.CGT_Last_Email_Status__c = EMAIL_STATUSES.get(myCase.EmailMessages[0].Status);
           }      
           update caseUpdate.values();   
    }
```

Now I want to write unit test for this method. I have written the following test but it keeps failing. I am new to Apex and don't know what is wrong with the test class:

Test method:

```
@IsTest
    private static void updateCaseLastEmailStatusTest() {
       
        // run test as CGT User
        System.runAs(TestDataFactory.createCgtUser()) {
           
            Account acc = TestDataFactory.createTestAccount();
            Case newCase = TestDataFactory.createCase();
           
            // get the record type of case
            newCase.RecordtypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('CaseRecordPage').getRecordTypeId();    

           
            String lastEmailStatusBefore = [SELECT Last_Email_Status__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :newCase.Id].Last_Email_Status__c;
            update newCase;
            System.assertEquals(null,lastEmailStatusBefore,'Email status should be empty on creation of case');
   
            EmailMessage email = TestDataFactory.createEmailMessage();            
            email.ParentId = newCase.Id;
            email.PE_RelatedPatient__c = acc.Id;
            email.RelatedToId = acc.Id;
            insert email;

            //then
            String lastEmailStatusAfter = [SELECT Last_Email_Status__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :newCase.Id].Last_Email_Status__c;
           
            System.assertEquals('New',lastEmailStatusAfter,'Email status should change');
        }        
    }
```

When I run the code, it gives me the following error:

> Class.PopulateCaseOnEmailTest.updateCaseLastEmailStatusTest: line 46,
> column 1
>
> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Email status should change:
> Expected: New, Actual: null

Is there any better way to write test for the above apex method

Comment: How exactly is it failing? Is it failing on running a line of test code? Or are one or more of your assertions failing? If so, what are you getting vs. what you are expecting?

Comment: I updated the question. please check now

Comment: You updated with the stack trace, but not the error message. Please [edit] your post to include the *message*.

Comment: The error msg is: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Email status should change: Expected: New, Actual: null

Comment: This does not look correct: `WHERE Id = :newCase.Id][0].Last_Email_Status__c`.  Notice the stray `]` just before the `[0]`.  Is that a copy/paste error or typo just in your question?  Or is that how your actual code is?

Comment: This is full line: [SELECT Last_Email_Status__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :newCase.Id][0]

Comment: You didn't fix the problem I pointed out in my answer. Your `Case` record still doesn't match your query in the code under test, because you reordered the assignment statement so that the `update` does nothing.

Comment: @DavidReed Can you help with that please. I don't know what do you mean by rearrange the code

Comment: Debug out `EMAIL_STATUSES` and `myCase.EmailMessages[0].Status`, is a value being found?

Comment: **1)** There is an assertion based off of `lastEmailStatusBefore` to check if the `Last_Email_Status__c` is `null`, which obviously passes.  **3)** There is an assertion based off of `lastEmailStatusAfter` to check if the `Last_Email_Status__c` is `New`, which is the one failing.  `lastEmailStatusBefore` and `lastEmailStatusAfter` use the exact same `SELECT` statement.  But there is no **2)** in between that would make any changes to the Case which would cause the same `SELECT` statement to retrieve different results.

Comment: @Moonpie i understand that but i don't know how to modify me test code to pass it. can you give me the code please

Answer (score 1):

You commented out the line of code that appears to make your test data match the query in your code under test:

```
newCase.RecordtypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('CaseRecordPage').getRecordTypeId();
//update newCase;
```

Hence, your query matches no records, and your test does nothing, failing the assertion.

---

You changed your code, but you didn't fix the issue identified above. **You must set the `Case` record type to `CaseRecordPage` and perform DML before your code under test is executed**. Otherwise, your `Case` does not match the query in your code under test.

As shown at the time of this writing, you set the `Case` record type *after* you perform `update` DML, which does nothing at all.

Comment: I updated the question. please check now

Comment: You omitted the actual error and included only the stacktrace. Regardless, please don't edit your posts in a way that makes answers like this one no longer make sense. One question per post is our model, and please make sure to apply a best effort to debugging first.

Comment: I changed the code again based on your recommendation but it still does not pass and gives me the same error.

Comment: You may have another unrelated issue, then, such as possibly not setting the EmailMessage Status field. You'll need to get hands-on and do some debugging to identify what is happening in your code.